# Google Docs API can't find Google Sheet with Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-docs-api

I have a Google Sheet: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/some_google_docs_id/edit#gid=0`, and I am trying to access it from a Python script:

```
def get_document(self, document_id):
    service = discovery.build('docs', 'v1', credentials=self.credentials)
    document = service.documents().get(documentId='some_document_id').execute()

    return document
```

But I get this error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/some_google_document_id?alt=json returned "Requested entity was not found.". Details: "Requested entity was not found.">
```

I can see that the error url is different from my document url, how can I instruct Google Api to use the right url?

Comment: Where did you get the document ID? Is the service account email authorized to read it? Do you have set the correct scopes to your credential?

Comment: The important thing is the Doc ID. This is a unique identifier for the document in question. Since you mention that the URL is different, can you confirm the Doc ID is the same?

Comment: Yes, the doc id is the same.

Comment: I got the document id from the URL when I created it. I didn't know I had to authorize it, I'll do it.

Comment: @HuLuViCa Did that solve your issue?

Comment: Nope, same exception

Comment: Who has authorised the script to run as them and does that Google account have access to the document?